# How to query a many-to-many when searching for certain permutation optimally?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, many-to-many, schema

So I have a schema that looks somewhat like this:

```
table recipes (int id)
table ingridients (int id)

table recipe_ingridients(recipe_id, ingridient_id)
```

What would be the best way to find if a recipe exists that consists of a specific set of ingridients?

Something like this (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT recipe WHERE ingridient_id`s = [3, 5, 7]
```

Is it a poorly designed schema for such use? If so is there a better way of approaching this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case when all members of the set must be present

```
select * 
from recipes r
where (select count(*) * 
              from recipe_ingridients ri
              where ri.ingridient_id in (3,5,7)
              and ri.recipe_id = r.id
              ) = 3
```

**Edit** Note it also returns recipes containg superset of the requied set. If an exact match is needed

```
select * 
from recipes r
where (select count(*) - count(case when ri.ingridient_id in (3,5,7) then 1 end) 
              from recipe_ingridients ri
              where  ri.recipe_id = r.id
              ) = 0
```

Comment: I noticed that in the second case, the result should be compared to 1 instead of 0, right?

Answer (score 0):

the data model , seems reasonable,you can use `exists in`:

```
select * from recipes r
where exists (select 1 from recipe_ingridients ri
              where ri.ingridient_id in ( 3,5,7)
               and ri.recipe_id = r.id
              )
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I phrased my question poorly. Edited. 
I meant to find a recipe that consists of the entire set we specified. No more ingridients, no less, only the ones specified.